# ruby: how to know if script is on 3rd retry?

Tags: ruby

```
begin
#some routine
rescue
retry
#on third retry, output "no dice!"
end
```

I want to make it so that on the "third" retry, print a message.

Comment: Instead of retry, put the thing in a 3.times loop?

Comment: you mean retry in a loop three times ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Possibly not the best solution, but a simple way is just to make a `tries` variable.

```
tries = 0
begin
  # some routine
rescue
  tries += 1
  retry if tries <= 3
  puts "no dice!"
end
```

Answer (score 10):

```
loop do |i|
  begin
    do_stuff
    break
  rescue
    raise if i == 2
  end
end
```

or

```
k = 0
begin
  do_stuff
rescue    
  k += 1
  k < 3 ? retry : raise
end
```

Comment: I like the first of these alternatives because its easy to remember and read. But it doesn't raise the error on the last try!

Comment: That's right, the first one is not suitable for most networking code, but it can be used when no exception should be raised.

Comment: Updated the first one to raise as well

Answer (score 5):

```
begin
  #your code
rescue
  retry if (_r = (_r || 0) + 1) and _r < 4  # Needs parenthesis for the assignment
  raise
end
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another gem named [retry-this](http://rubygems.org/gems/retry-this) that helps with such a thing.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > require 'retry-this'
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > RetryThis.retry_this(:times => 3) do |attempt|
ruby-1.9.2-p0 >     if attempt == 3
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>      puts "no dice!"
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>    else
ruby-1.9.2-p0 >       puts "trying something..."
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>      raise 'an error happens' # faking a consistent error
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>    end
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>  end
trying something...
trying something...
no dice!
 => nil
```

The good thing about such a gem as opposed to raw begin..rescue..retry is that we can avoid an infinite loop or introducing a variable just for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Integer
  def times_try
    n = self
    begin
      n -= 1
      yield
    rescue
      raise if n < 0
      retry
    end
  end
end

begin
  3.times_try do
    #some routine
  end
rescue
  puts 'no dice!'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The gem [attempt](http://gemcutter.org/gems/attempt) is designed for this, and provides the option of waiting between attempts. I haven't used it myself, but it seems to be a great idea.

Otherwise, it's the kind of thing blocks excel at, as other people have demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

```
def method(params={})
  tries ||= 3
  # code to execute
rescue Exception => e
  retry unless (tries -= 1).zero?
  puts "no dice!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Proc.class_eval do
  def rescue number_of_attempts=0
    @n = number_of_attempts
      begin
        self.call 
      rescue => message
        yield message, @n if block_given?
        @n -= 1
        retry if @n > 0
      end
    end
end
```

And then you can use it as:

```
-> { raise 'hi' }.rescue(3)
-> { raise 'hi' }.rescue(3) { |m, n| puts "message: #{m}, 
                                           number of attempts left: #{n}" }
```