# how to make an obfuscate id with a length of 16 characters and without collision

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What i want to do is to make an obfuscate id when i show a user url, i want to have an obfuscate id with **exactly 16 characters** in length, and **without collision**, so for example instead of

```
http://localhost:3000/users/2
```

i want something like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/users/3a5643f943cc3a44
```

i already find the same question in other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305036/how-do-i-obfuscate-the-ids-of-my-records-in-rails) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527787/how-to-obscure-the-id-in-a-url-ruby-on-rails) and also others... but can't find an answer of what i want exactly.

**===========**
**Update:**
**===========**

**It's been some years now since I posted this question, I just want to mention that there is a super helpful gem called [hashids](https://github.com/peterhellberg/hashids.rb) which I use in all my recent projects, it's straight forward and easy to use :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64. This following related question can also help: [Best way to create unique token in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021372/best-way-to-create-unique-token-in-rails)

16 characters is the default length (but the length is variable, as can be seen in the documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-urlsafe_base64)

Comment: i add the first argument for SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 like this SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(12, false) which gives me exactly 16 characters in length, but i'm not sure what is the number of possibility when take juste 16 in length